# Creating objects without using InjectMocks is causing issue for httpClient

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a class which has a default constructor. Inside this constructor so many members are initialized like:

```
public classs MyClass{
private String variable1=null;
private String param1="2000";
private String param2="2000";
public MyClass() {

        variable1 = getProperty("iaRequestPath");
        timeout = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("param1"));
        reuqestUrl = getProperty("reuqestUrl");
        try {
            String maxConnection = getProperty("maxConnection");
            int connections =0;
             int param3=0;
            param3 = validateMethod(maxConnection);//Here parse Int will happen
             param4 = validateResource(defaultMaxConnPerRoute);
            param5 = validateResource(maxConnPerIAroute);
            HttpCoreConnectionFactory factory = new HttpCoreConnectionFactory(parma1, param2, null, 0, 
                                                                null, "SOME_VALUE");
            httpclient = factory.getPooledHttpCoreClient(param3, param4, param5, reuqestUrl);
        } catch (Exception exp) {

        }

    }
```

If I use `@InjectMocks` I am not able to mock constructor members  since constructor will be called before mocking happens inside my test class.
I avoided using inject mocks and manually created objects in my test class.
like `MyClass testClass=new MyClass();` 
 and mocked httpClient like

```
HttpClient httpClient =PowerMockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
```

> httpClient always throws null in my actual code since HttpClient is initailized  inside constructor .How to
>   overcome this situation Basically I don't need value of httpclient 
>   from constructor initialization instead I need it from Mock

Though I have mocked its not getting mocked value.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Powermock to mock the creation of the factory. Then mock the `getPooledHttpCoreClient` method to return a mock of `httpClient`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(HttpCoreConnectionFactory.class)
public class MyClassTest{


@Mock
private HttpCoreConnectionFactory factoryMock;

@Mock
private HttpClient httpClientMock;

@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

@Test
public void testMethod(){

    // Arrange
    PowerMockito.whenNew(HttpCoreConnectionFactory.class)
     .withArguments(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()...).thenReturn(factoryMock);

    doReturn(httpClientMock).when(factoryMock)
        .getPooledHttpCoreClient(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()...);

    // prepare the httpClientMock using when() etc..

    // Act
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    // assertions
```

Comment: Thanks Mac I will try this tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Hi Mac it worked like a charm for this.Now I am facing another issue which is not able to mock inputstream reader.while loop it is behaving crazily it enters while loop and not coming out.Do I need to use verify for this

Comment: PowerMockito.doReturn(inputStream).when(httpEntity).getContent();
PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class).withArguments(inputStream,Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(inputSteamReader);

Comment: while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(line); }

Comment: PowerMockito.when(bufferReader.readLine()).thenReturn("line").thenReturn(null);
  PowerMockito.when(inputSteamReader.read()).thenReturn(10).thenReturn(-1);

Comment: Appreciate all your support.

Comment: I was just going to ask about the code.. but if you solved it.. then its cool. Anyway glad i could help